# Help wanted with customising the markdown panel in gedit

Tags: themes, gtk, gedit, plugins

I have gedit 3.6.2 (Lubuntu 13.04) and I've installed a plugin from [gedit-markdown: support for Markdown language in gedit](https://web.archive.org/web/20140716000648/http://www.jpfleury.net/en/software/gedit-markdown.php) that allows me to preview markdown text in a bottom or side panel within gedit.

I want to know if it's possible to change the background color of the lower panel from white to something else like #999.

I'm using Greybird (from "shimmer-themes" in the Software Center) in which I've already modified `gtk.css` to have the following colors:

```css
/* default color scheme */
@define-color bg_color #9e9e9e;
@define-color fg_color #000043;
@define-color base_color #8e8e8e;
@define-color text_color #000;
@define-color selected_bg_color #091825;
@define-color selected_fg_color #a2e5fb;
@define-color tooltip_bg_color #333333;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color #aaaaaa;
```

Despite these changes to `gtk.css` (which are effective for other gtk3 apps), the background color in the bottom panel stays white:

[image: gedit-markdown plugin panel]

For the upper (main) panel, I use a slightly modified Cobalt color scheme (`/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/cobalt.xml`).

Comment: I don't think preview-panel depends on gtk-colors.That plugin source has a `styles/classicmarkdown.xml` file from which all markdown related colors derived for preview-panel.You can make necessary change & recompile it to see whether it works or not.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, if you are referring to `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`, these are the files present: check-style.sh, cobalt.xml, kate.xml, styles.rng, classic.xml, oblivion.xml, tango.xml. Are you using this plugin? Could you please provide the full path of `styles/classicmarkdown.xml`? In any case, the lower panel provides _html_ content and not _markdown_.

Comment: Try looking under `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`. And do NOT change anything `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`, copy it to `~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`, change anything from there.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, I do have the file you mentioned but the point is that that file affects only content in the upper panel which has markdown content. The lower panel which previews content as html is unaffected. I want to change the background color of the lower panel.

Comment: I noticed that. In older version it used to use a `html-template`, but now the markdown-preview is handled by `python-markdown` which converts markdown to html & hard-coded into source. Go to `~/.local/lib/python-$version/site-packages/markdown/docs`. Inside you will find `basic.css`, `default.css` & `_tempalte.html`. You might look inside. Let me know if that helps. As a last resort you could try ask the author of this plugin.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, I looked at `basic.css` and `default.css` but it's not clear what they apply to. Anyway, I modified a few background-color values and link colors in both files, but there's no effect on the lower panel contents. Interestingly, by fiddling with `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/markdow-preview/__init__.py`, I could alter the appearance of the text and background color of the tooltip that appears when hovering the mouse cursor over a link in the lower panel: `self.urlTooltip.modify_bg(0, Gdk.color_parse("#FE768E"))` and `label.modify_fg(0, Gdk.color_parse("#500000"))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A picture that worth a hundred words:

[image: Markdown Preview in Gedit]

And here's markdown preview in side-by-side mode:

[image: Markdown preview side-by-side]

Or try to change [browser's default CSS for HTML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements).

Comment: I'll see how I can give this answer another 50 points if the rules allow :) Thank you so much. I was getting quite frustrated.

Comment: I added another image for side-by-side preview.

Comment: I got an answer that allows me to point to a css file so that I don't have to modify each markdown file: [Markdown preview Python-based plugin for gedit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18026416/1771119).